# How to? Database design to sum user selections

Tags: mysql

I have designed a database with two tables. Table 1 has two columns,

- `moodID` (primary key)
- `TYPE`

Table 2 has

- `logId` (primary key)
- `userId`
- `moodID` (foreign key)

Table 1 has 11 entries for example:

```
moodID 1 = Excited
moodID 2 = Happy
moodID 3 = Calm etc all the way up to moodId 11.
```

Currently when I run the query

```
  SELECT Mood FROM Cbt WHERE userId = '1';
```

I get this Json:

```
  [{"mood":"1"},{"mood":"1"},{"mood":"3"}]
```

These ints represent the PK in the mood table not the total number of times the user has selected that mood.

I'm trying to design the tables in a way where I can run a query which will return the number of times a user has inputted a mood type. I would like to be able to make a pie chart which shows the mood name and the total number of times the user selected that mood. Could someone with a some database design experience nudge me in the right direction to set the tables up in such a way where I can achieve this outcome. I would greatly appreciate it any help you could provide.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting the question tool was really buggy and wouldnt let me post the question until I indented lines 4 spaces which were not even code....

Comment: Your query should only return a list on `INT` values, not a JSON expression. How are you getting JSON?

Comment: select type, count(*) from table2 join table1 using (moodID) where userID = 1 group by userID;

Comment: Im using Retrofit to feed it into the android app where Im making the piechart. I didnt want to get into all that cause its a bit outside the scope and I can handle that side of things myself. I think the problem lays with the structure of my databse itself

Comment: The table structure seems fine. Use: `select moodID, count(*) as times from Cbt where userId = '1' group by moodID`.

Comment: Thats worked a charm! Thanks guys, really appreciate it!

Comment: Is there anyway I can get the mood name to show instead of it being represented by its INT value?